# What is wrong with my MainActivity.kt file?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating a Calculator Application.
Whenever a user changes the orientation of the device, the current app activity gets destroyed and recreated. So to fix that problem(i.e. get all the data back) I did this:

1. Declaring some variables

```
private const val STATE_OPERAND1 = "data"
private const val STATE_PENDING_OPERATION = "PENDING_OPERATION"
private const val STATE_OPERAND1_STORED = "data"
```

2. Overriding the 'onSaveInstanceState' function

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    if (operand1 != null) {
        outState.putDouble(STATE_OPERAND1, operand1!!)
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_OPERAND1_STORED, true)
    }
    outState.putString(STATE_PENDING_OPERATION, pendingOperation)
}
```

3. Overriding the 'onRestoreInstanceState' function

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    operand1 = if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_OPERAND1_STORED, false))
        savedInstanceState.getDouble(STATE_OPERAND1)
    else
        null
    result.setText(operand1.toString())    // Marked Line 1
    pendingOperation = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_PENDING_OPERATION)
    displayOperation.text = pendingOperation
    }
```

The 'Marked Line 1' in the 3rd code is not required, the reason I added is to find out the error. In this code the *result* test box clears it's previous text and has the text 'null' entered.

However, when I changed the declaration in 1
from `private const val STATE_OPERAND1 = "data"` to `private const val STATE_OPERAND1 = "STATE_OPERAND1"`

The *result* text box showed the text it was supposed to and everything worked properly. The application worked as long as all the three declaration in the 1st code were different. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the initial declarations:

```
private const val STATE_OPERAND1 = "data"
private const val STATE_OPERAND1_STORED = "data"
```

this line:

```
outState.putDouble(STATE_OPERAND1, operand1!!)
```

sets inside the `Bundle` object the `Double` value `operand1!!` by the key `"data"`.
The next line:

```
outState.putBoolean(STATE_OPERAND1_STORED, true)
```

sets again (overwrites) inside the `Bundle` object the `Boolean` value `true` by the key `"data"`.
The result is that the previous `Double` value is now **lost** and the only value that exists is the new `Boolean` value.
So what you have is only one `Boolean` value.
When you changed to:

```
private const val STATE_OPERAND1 = "STATE_OPERAND1"
private const val STATE_OPERAND1_STORED = "data"
```

this conflict vanished, because you had 2 different keys and the 2 values were saved properly without overwriting each other.

Comment: Ohh... that makes sense... Thanks a lot. I'm new to a lot of this.